# Outlook - How to Programmatically Select a PST Folder

Tags: c#, outlook-addin

If I have PST folder structure like this in my Outlook

```
Root
   + Folder A
   - Folder B
     |- Folder 1
     |- Folder 2
   + Folder C
```

How do I select a folder programatically so that the folder appears selected and outlook pane shows content of that folder in C#?

For example in above structure, if I say right click on Folder C and click on a context menu `"Go To Folder A`", how do I select Folder A programatically?

Comment: Take a moment to read through the [editing help](//stackoverflow.com/editing-help) in the help center. Formatting on Stack Overflow is different than other sites. The better your post looks, the easier it is for others to read and understand it.

Comment: what have you tried on your own.. do you have any code you can post? when you right click how are you storing the location / folder paths of Folders A - B or Folder 1 - 2 or Folder C...etc..?

Comment: Nothing tried so far, I am trying to figure out how to do it.  But assuming I have the paths, how do I navigate to it?  Thanks

Comment: Have you googled anything?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider setting `Application.ActiveExplorer.Folder` to the folder you want selected.

Comment: Thanks, exactly what I needed